# Cannot Load RMagic in Rails, but can in IRB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, rmagick

I'm having trouble getting RMagick to work properly. When I run the require in IRB:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'RMagick'
=> true
```

But when I try to include it in my Rails app I get:

```
no such file to load -- RMagick
```

I installed RMagick through the Gem.

```
gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (1.0.18)
daemon_controller (0.2.6)
fastthread (1.0.7)
minitest (1.6.0)
passenger (3.0.8)
rack (1.3.2)
rake (0.8.7)
rdoc (2.5.8)
rmagick (2.13.1)
```

Ruby version:

```
ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [x86_64-linux]
```

Passenger for Rails is loading:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.8/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.8
```

Could the difference in ruby versions between the passenger module and the console be a problem?

Thanks so much!
~James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely- the ruby versions need to be the same.  I would urge you to move over to using RVM instead: http://beginrescueend.com/ as it'll be a lot painless in the long run.

Comment: The whole idea of having different version of ruby is a bit much for the current project so I've reinstalled everything and strictly used 1.9.1. However, it's still not starting =( Now it's giving the LoadError on server startup rather than on the controller though...

Answer (score 0):

I setup RMagick in the past and based on a quick glance at old code, I had to do this:

```
require 'RMagick'
include Magick # not sure why, but we always have to do this w/ RMagick.
```

I also remember that doing this worked on one particular system:

```
require 'rmagick' # lowercase version of require 'RMagick'
```

Comment: Yeah, I have Magick after it. I reinstalled everything, but it's still not working. However now the server refuses to even start, whereas before the controller would fail.

Comment: Just personal opinion here... abandon RMagick and use ImageScience instead: https://github.com/seattlerb/image_science